# Want to rewrite requested URL to another URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the URL http://example.com/9879879870/hello to
http://example.com?phone=9879879870&message=hello

Is it possible. If yes, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you want that the second URL would be the first one, correct? That is a topic regarding mod_rewrite e.g., depending on the Server and not on PHP.

Comment: @D.Schalla what are you talking about? What he's asking is possible. I'm not up to scratch with `htaccess` but it's definately possible.

Comment: it looks like you already have some sort of url rewriting on your htaccess. If you have please post it so we can look

Comment: Ryan, what are you talking about? I asked if I understood him correct, since the Layout of the first URL already looks like an Rewrite, like Liam said.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /phone=$1&message=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Would rewrite `http://example.com/9879879870/hello` to `http://example.com/phone=9879879870&message=hello`. However, I think you'll probably want to pass the two arguments as a query parameter, so you'll need to add `?` too:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?phone=$1&message=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes. Actually it was a mistake. I edited the question.

Comment: Not working.. I opened the URL localhost/9879879870/hello but it says Not Found.

Comment: Are the files inside your root? Do you have a Directory Index defined?

Comment: For example is there an `index.php`, or some kind of other file you've specified as the index for the root dir?

Comment: When I see the browser, the URl remains the same. I mean it is not getting changed to localhost?phone=9879879870&message=hello

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure Apache **mod_rewrite** is enabled

Later you can write following lines in **.htaccess** and place it in your root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?phone=$1&message=$2
```

Comment: by specifying index.php here, it becomes specific that we want index.php file to be used for targeting the rewritten URLs. (.*) here means any character that comes in here, will be referred.